# Bug in nominating question for reopening

Tags: bug, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

1. A question was closed
2. As user, I decide to vote for reopening.
3. I click on the ***Reopen*** link.
4. An confirm alert appears.

   ```
   Nominate this question for reopening?
                          <Cancel> <OK>
   ```
5. I click **OK** button. The alert is closed.
6. Now under the question the ***Reopen (1)*** appears.
7. **I don't refresh the page.** I click again on the ***Reopen*** link, and the confirm alert from 4. appears again.
8. If I press **OK** again, the alert is closed. **--> Go back to 6.**

I guess it's a bug that has to be reported here.

An error message has to appear: "You already voted for reopening this question...".

Comment: What happens if you press OK again?

Comment: @OldCheckmark The alert disappears. Nothing more...

Comment: I sort-of expect that since you now can cancel close votes, you can also cancel reopen votes.

Comment: @DanielFischer nope, we can't cancel reopen votes, there's no UI for this.

Comment: If I refresh the page and click Reopen the error appears: "You already voted to reopen" (something like this)..

Comment: Even after reloading the page, the dialog still appears and if you click OK red message sometime appear, but most of the times no message is displayed. Bug indeed! :(

Comment: I am happy that I've reported it. :-)